# how does alamofire know when there is a change in a JSON online?

Tags: alamofire

im working on an app which fetches json from a website. everything is working properly and im using alamofire .

but for some reason, when i post new content on the website and the json file changes, alamofire doesnt get the new content. instead, it loads the content from the cache instead of redownloading the new content.

the only workaround to this is to clear the cache which is a way that i do not prefer since the user will have to download the content all over again at each view load.

so what im asking is, is there a way to notify the alamofire method about the new content and try to load the new content instead of having me to implement a method to clear the cache?

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire uses the Foundation URL loading system, which relies on [`NSURLCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/). The cache behavior for HTTP requests is determined by the contents of your HTTP response's `Cache-Control` headers. For example, you may wish to configure your server to specify `must-revalidate`:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
```

You should also make sure your server is specifying `ETag` and `Content-Length` headers to make it easy to tell when content has changed.

[NSHipster's writeup on `NSURLCache`](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/) has a few good examples. If you're totally new to web caching, I recommend you read the very helpful [section 13 of the HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), and possibly also [this caching tutorial](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).